# Office 365, Sharepoint, List of Html <h1> contents

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, html, office365

I am new to Sharepoint (365) and try to make some Wiki-Webpage.
But there is no Contents overview like on Wikipedia or Mediawiki.
Since Sharepoint doesn't know PHP I try to create some content-menu in Javascript.

When I add Javascript into the source code of my current webpage, sharepoint removes it with some warning information. The warning wants me to use the webpart option.

Now I have added the js-code in the Webpart, but it looks like the script can't do what I want because it is not included in the site HTML.

When I test the js-code with some alert("test"); I get a reaction.
But when I try to get some html content with document.getElementsByTagName('h2'); it does nothing.

Is Javascript the correct way to make some 'content'-overview by lookup the html 'h1' tags?
Normaly I would use PHP but Sharepoint doesn't know the language.
What is the server-sided language of Sharepoint?

Comment: I modified my answer, use this script, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `Content Editor Webpart` to add your javascript.

Steps to add `Content Editor Webpart`

1. Edit that page
2. click on Add a WebPart
3. select Media and Content

Modify your script like this:-

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
 var getbyid = document.getElementById("mydiv1");
 alert(getbyid.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].firstChild.data); 
};
</script>
<div id="mydiv1"> 
<h1>Heading 1</h1> 
<p>Some text for Heading 1.</p> 
<h2>Heading 2</h2> 
<p>Some text for Heading 2.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added the new Webpart Conent Editor now, but i can not get the html information. I included <h1> text in the Webpart and outside. Then when I try alert(document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].firstChild.data); I can not see any content in here. But the code should work... http://jsfiddle.net/1hkg3t7x/

Comment: @user3772108 write your javascript like this `window.onload = function () { alert(document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].firstChild.data);};`

Comment: This is the full code I included in the Webpart:

<script="text/javascript">

alert(document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].firstChild.data);

</script> </p> 
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Text for Heading 1.</p>
<p>&#160;</p>
<h2>Heading 2&#160;</h2>
<p>Text for Heading 2.</p>

Comment: @user3772108 i have edited my answer, please use this script in your content editor webpart.

Comment: Sharepoint executes the Javascript and I see a empty warning message. But the warning should display the h1 content ("Heading 1" as example).

Comment: @user3772108 modified my answer, please use this script

Comment: It works! But this means I have to insert a <div id> in the HTML?
Sharepoint creates the <h1> tags himself. This did not include some <div id>
Thats the reason why I try to do this without a div tag...

Comment: reason is it will start searching from start of the page and page starts with master page as you might be aware of.

Comment: Ok that means the script will work for the full page and not only the Webpart? Is this correct?

Comment: yes it is true. you can access any element of that page from your webpart, that why i wrapped the html with a div.